# I cannot catch index from random.shuffle method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I cannot catch index from random.shuffle method.
An error happens

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
```

My code is

```
if __name__ =="__main__":
    bell_nums = range(1,6)
    pairs = list(itertools.combinations(bell_nums,2))

    for pair in pairs:
        bell_num1=int(pair[0])
        bell_num2 = int(pair[1])
        train_data = np.empty((0,12),float)
        train_label = np.array([])
        test_data = np.empty((0,12),float)
        test_label = np.array([])
        noise_nums = list(range(1,12))
        level_nums = list(range(0,10))
        random.shuffle(noise_nums)

        nfft=2048 
        nceps = 12 

        for noise_nums_index in noise_nums[0:10]:
            random.shuffle(level_nums)
            files_name = glob.glob("learning_sample/%d_%d_%d.wav" % (bell_num1,noise_nums_index,level_nums))
            for file_name in files_name:
                feature = get_feature(files_name,nfft,nceps)
                if len(train_data) ==0:
                    train_data=feature
                else:
                    train_data=np.vstack((train_data,feature))
                train_label=np.append(train_label,bell_num1)
            files_name="learning_sample/%d_%d_%d.wav"% (bell_num1,noise_num,level_nums[8])
            feature = get_feature(file_name,nfft,nceps)
            if len(test_data) ==0:
                test_data=feature
            else:
                test_data=np.vstack((test_data,feature))
            test_label=np.append(test_label,bell_num1)
```

I think `level_nums` is list type,so this error happen.
But I cannot come up with the way to catch index from random.shuffle method in this case.
I wanna name "learning_sample/%d_%d_%d.wav"  this file by using noise_nums_index's number and level_nums's number randomly.In this case, how can I do to name this part?How can I write this?Should I use for statement for `random.shuffle(level_nums)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a random element in `level_nums` you should use: `random.choice(level_nums)`

In your code:

```
for noise_nums_index in noise_nums[0:10]:
    files_name = glob.glob("learning_sample/%d_%d_%d.wav" % (bell_num1,noise_nums_index,random.choice(level_nums)))
```

Note that since `noise_nums` is not define in the code you provide I was no able to check the full code. There might be some other errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) method from standard python library.

for example:

```
random.randrange(1, 12, 1)
```

or [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) method:

```
a = list(range(1,12))
random.choice(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`level_nums` is a list and you are pointing it at a `%d` format string.

If you are just looking for a random int, and because you are already using numpy have you considered using `np.random.choice()`? That would remove the need to even use the shuffle method.

```
>>> np.random.choice(level_nums)
3
>>> np.random.choice(level_nums)
8
```

Or just the random int function and get rid of level_nums completely

```
>>> np.random.randint(1, 11)
6
```